# How to customize Hasse diagram in R?

Tags: r, plot, partial-ordering

Working on a Partial Order Hasse plot for a research paper. Looking to customize the output of hasse() function from the hasseDiagram package but not sure how. I have taken a look under the hood, but it is unclear where I might be able to set parameters to drive:

1. Label Colors
2. Arrow Sizes and Shapes

Any ideas?

Example:

```
library("hasseDiagram")
test_data <- generateRandomData(20, 3, 0.5)
hasse(test_data)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make a "minimum reproducible example"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Just added. There are no graphical parameters to add. This is more a question of how to "dive" into the function and customize to accept visual parameters.

Comment: `getAnywhere("hasse")` should show you the source code